# The Data is printed in console, Assigned to $scope but NOT printing in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

**Update**

**Problem:**
Let me try to explain what I want in one or two lines, In Demo 1 where I've used Angular Datatables when I click on Edit button the data DOES NOT appear in Edit form, whereas in Demo 2 I haven't used any datatables but the data is clearly appearing in edit form, I want the data to appear in Demo1 using Datatables. The data is inside the $scope.update but for some reasons it is not appearing in HTML whereas using the same HTML It works perfectly without datatables.

Demo1: http://plnkr.co/edit/EXXbkPUHfxcZ3blzvMaz?p=preview

Demo2: http://plnkr.co/edit/QYZzmJNwWTQaIgvUkRzQ?p=preview

**Background**

Initially on the left hand side the Data is inserted from a form which contain one Input type and one Select (Colony Type), there are two forms Insert, Update form on the left hand side one form is for insertion and one for editing, when the insertion form is visible the edit form is hidden and vice versa, on the right hand side the list of data is displayed with the help of datatables along with Edit and Delete button, Important thing is the buttons are made inside the DataTable code and not on HTML page, now Delete and Insert works absolutely fine, but Edit !! No it doesn't.

**Problem**

**Case 1: (When I use Datatables)** 
when the Edit button (CODED INSIDE DATATABLES) is clicked an ID is sent, In the Below picture the Id is consoled "47" then an $http request is made which brings the Data and printed in console. but when I try to inject the values back to Update form it doesn't work, although when I consoled $scope the values are injected into update object but not printing on HTML page.

**Case 2: (When I don't Use Datatables)**
If I don't use Datatables and click the Edit the button every thing works absolutely fine and the data is injected into update object and printed on HTML page.

**HTML PAGE:**

**If DataTables are Used**

```
<!-- IF DataTables are Used For printing the Data on Right Side-->
<div ng-controller="colony_Controller as Main_Module">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" align="center" datatable="" dt-options="Main_Module.dtOptions" dt-columns="Main_Module.dtColumns" class="row-border hover">
</table>
```

**If DataTables are NOT Used**

```
<!-- If DataTables are NOT Used for Printing the Data on Right Side -->

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 323px;" aria-label="">Colony Name</th>

            <th style="width: 170px;" aria-label="">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="colony in es_colony_details" >
            <td style="width: 323px;" aria-label="">{{colony.es_colony_name}}</td>
            <td>
                <button ng-click="EditColonyData(colony.es_colony_id)" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</button>
                <button ng-click="DeleteColonyData(colony.es_colony_id)" class="btn btn-danger">
                    <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i> Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Controller**

```
    Main_Module.controller('colony_Controller', function colony_Controller($window, $scope, $http, bootbox, $compile, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, SimpleHttpRequest, DelMainRecPicRecUnlinkPic, message)
 {
     $scope.field = {};
     $scope.update = {};
     var dtInstance = {};

     /********************************** FETCH DATA START *******************************/
     $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/SELECT/es_colony_type').success(function successCallback(data)
     {
         $scope.es_colony_type = data.es_colony_type;
         //console.log(data.es_colony_type);
     });

     // ONLY USED WHEN Datatable are NOT 
      //$http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/SELECT/es_colony").success(function successCallback(data)
      //{
      //    $scope.es_colony_details = data.es_colony;
      //    console.log(data.es_colony);
      //});
     /********************************** FETCH DATA END *********************************/

     /********************************** DISPLAY DATA START *******************************/
     var vm = this;
     vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
     .fromFnPromise(function()
     {
         return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/SELECT/es_colony')
             .then(function(response)
             {
                 return response.data.es_colony;
             });
     })
     .withOption('order', [0, 'desc'])
     .withDisplayLength(5)
     .withPaginationType('simple_numbers')
     .withOption('createdRow', function(row, data, dataIndex)
     {
         $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
     })
     vm.dtColumns =
     [
         DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_colony_name').withTitle('Colony'),
         DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable().withOption('width', '31%')
         .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta)
         {
             return '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="EditColonyData(' + data.es_colony_id + ');">' +
                 '<i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit' + '</button>&nbsp;' +
                 '<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="DeleteColonyData(' + data.es_colony_id + ');">' +
                 '<i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i> Delete' + '</button>';
         })
     ];

     $scope.EditColonyData = function(id)
     {
         console.log(id);
         $http.get('api/SELECTBYID/es_colony/es_colony_id/'+id)
             .success(function(data)
             {
                 console.log(data);
                 console.log($scope);


                 $scope.YesEdit = true;
                 $scope.update = data.es_colony[0];

                 // **This is where I'm injecting data Back to $scope object**

                 $scope.update.es_colony_type_id = data.es_colony[0].es_colony_type_id;

             });
     };
```

Comment: Unfortunately, while you may have an answerable question, it's buried in the question body here.  You have provided *too much* code to really scan quickly and understand what's going on, and code that relies upon external data in order to create a working model to test it.  You should try to reduce the amount of code presented here, as many people will just ignore the question entirely as it is currently written.

Comment: OK Thanks let me reduce it

Comment: One of the reasons we close questions is when the user doesn't have the minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue in the question itself. that cuts both ways (from not including code, to including too much code).  We want to help you; but you should take a step back and reproduce this issue in the simplest way possible (and with the least amount of code), and then share that code with us as an MCVE.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I think the poster was making an effort to correct this behavior;  to be clear, the question now is much better than when it was first posted, and it does include links to two different MCVE.  I'm all for question improvement and have been trying to encourage the user to improve the content, but I'm not sure the unilateral closure was exactly warranted.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up `$scope` and `this` for your controller model.

Since you are using `controllerAs` alias....all your data model needs to be bound to `this` in controller or you need to get rid of alias for controler and only use `$scope`

Most people would recommend using the alias and `this`

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned by @charlietfl in his answer, your example using `dataTables` is incorrectly assigning the same controller twice, once with `ng-controller="colony_Controller"` and once with `ng-controller="colony_Controller as Main_Module`.  The data tables inside the second copy of the controller will not have access to the variables in the first controller.

```
<div ng-controller="colony_Controller">
....
    <div ng-controller="colony_Controller as Main_Module">
      <table align="center" datatable="" dt-options="Main_Module.dtOptions" dt-columns="Main_Module.dtColumns" class="row-border hover">
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

To correct this, you need to choose between using the first syntax (`$scope`) or the second (`controller as`) and ensure that all the code is using the same format.

In this modified version, `dtOptions` and `dtColumns` have been moved to `$scope`, and the extra controller removed:

```js
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
  .fromSource('data_colony.json')
  ...

$scope.dtColumns = [
  ...
];
```

```html
<div ng-controller="colony_Controller">
  ...
  <div>
    <table align="center" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="row-border hover">
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GB0IIQQoEaLN0QPBSjCz?p=preview

Comment: Thankyou Sooooo much Claies, Really Appreciate your help.